# I cannot umount system even if i have detached my HDD from system completely. Rsync process are open

Tags: rsync, umount

I cannot umount system even if i have detached my HDD from system completely. Rsync process are open

I detached my HDD from usb port completely but stills it shows it as mounted.
I found that there are open processes that I cannot kill them (status D).
What I must do to umount the HDD without reboot?

```
sudo fuser -vmMki  /mnt/HDD_bckp/

                     USER        PID ACCESS COMMAND
/mnt/HDD_bckp:
                     root     kernel mount /mnt/HDD_bckp
                     elias     61428 F.... rsync
                     elias     61430 F.c.. rsync
                     root      225357 f.... (fwupdmgr
                     elias     333843 f.... baloo_filemetad
                     elias     337939 f.... baloo_filemetad
                     root      347688 f.... (ostnamed
                     elias     351650 f.... baloo_filemetad
```

pressing "y" to kill them all but dont kill them.

```
sudo lsof  /dev/sdb1
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1000/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
COMMAND      PID  USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF      NODE NAME
rsync      61428 elias    3w   REG   8,17  9140924        14 /mnt/HDD_bckp/09aug.log (deleted)
rsync      61430 elias  cwd    DIR   8,17    12288         2 /mnt/HDD_bckp
rsync      61430 elias    1u   REG   8,17        0 117864530 /mnt/HDD_bckp/_X_PICS/400_n.jpg.oF86P8
(fwupdmgr 225357  root    4u   DIR   8,17    12288         2 /run/systemd/unit-root/mnt/HDD_bckp
baloo_fil 333843 elias    8r   REG   8,17   207541        96 /mnt/HDD_bckp/oZ.jpg
baloo_fil 337939 elias    8r   REG   8,17  2619650        20 /mnt/HDD_bckp/344.gif
(ostnamed 347688  root    4u   DIR   8,17    12288         2 /run/systemd/unit-root/mnt/HDD_bckp
baloo_fil 351650 elias    8r   REG   8,17   150826       122 /mnt/HDD_bckp/7839_n.jpg
```

Comment: Do you know what happened to the disk (e.g: did it fail or get removed unexpectedly)? Can you share the relevant `dmesg` output?

Comment: i have usb hub with buttons, it was stuck in rsync and i closed the button and then i removed it.

Comment: `[ 1871.047146] usb 4-5.2.3: reset SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 44 using xhci_hcd
[ 1871.073537] sd 4:0:0:0: [sde] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_TIME_OUT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=30s
[ 1871.073540] sd 4:0:0:0: [sde] tag#0 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 00 08 00 00
[ 1871.073551] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sde, sector 2048 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 1 prio class 0`